# Serve the index.html page at root in grizzly

Tags: java, grizzly

In a single page web application scenario, if I'm serving all my static files on the `/static` route:

```
server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(new StaticHttpHandler("src/main/webapp"), "/static");
```

Where the `webapp` directory contain all my `*.js` and `*.css` files in addition to  `index.html`.

How can I serve the `index.html` on `/` instead if `/static/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(new StaticHttpHandler("src/main/webapp"), "/");
```

Comment: I want to serve all my static content on `/static/` root **except** for the `index.html`, is there a solution to create an `HttpHandler` to serve only `index.html` on the root route?

Comment: Mapping the handler to `"/"`, keeping index.html under `src/main/webapp` and moving all other resources to `src/main/webapp/static` doesn't work?

Comment: Also worth trying is adding 2 separate StaticHttpHandlers, one for "/" and another for "/static". I've never tried this though. Either way for sure your `index.html` needs to stay in a separate folder than your other resources.

Comment: I think that your two propositions will obviously work, I want to create an `HttpHandler` that serve just a file, not a directory, worth a try ?

Comment: As far as I remember `StaticHttpHandler` only takes a directory, so unless you create a directory specific to your `index.html` I can't see any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can implement it like:

```
server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(new StaticHttpHandler("src/main/webapp"), "/static", "/index.html");
```

but in that case "index.html" will be accessible from "/index.html", "/static/index.html", "/static/" and it will be very difficult to maintain relative paths within index.html file.

I would suggest to implement additional "forwarder" HttpHandler, that will forward "/index.html" requests to "/static/index.html", it's easier and should solve the relative paths problem.